# django: pip install 'app' installs to the venv?

Tags: django

I read that it is not proper to have the venv in the git repo, which should be taken care of by requirements.txt, but I have run into a problem...

If I am working in my venv and I do a pip install of some app, it installs it into the venv site-packages. It still works and everything if I add it to installed_apps, but what if I make some changes within that directory? Then git doesn't track them and I am out of luck when I try to push it.

What is the proper way to do this?

EDIT: I must be having a huge miscommunication here so let me explain with a concrete example...

1. I run...
   pip install django-messages
2. This then install django messages into me venv, I know I can run...
   local...pip freeze > requirements.txt
   remote....pip install -r requirements.txt
3. My problem is that I want to make changes to django-messages/templates or django-messages/views thus deviating my django-messages from the one which can be installed from requirements.txt

I don't see how these are to remain in my venv without being completely uneditable/untrackable

Comment: As you wrote, your venv shoudn't be in your repo and more, it should included in your .gitignore. If you want to have easily a venv I suggest you to use tox.

Comment: I get that, but my main problem is the fact that pip install 'app' installs to the venv...if I then make changes to these apps in the venv and it is untracked, how do my changes get pushed?

Comment: You want to edit the code of third-party apps in your site-packages? Don't do that. Any custom code you write should be in your project. You can override templates and write your own views within your project, you don't change the code of the app itself.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Is there a place in the docs I can read over doing this? I can't come up with the words to track it down. Do I just create a bare 'appname' dir in my project directory and then add a templates (or whatever it may be) file/folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your edits it looks like what you want to do is fork the django-messages library. This means that installing it into site-packages is a bad idea in the first place, since site-packages is not supposed to be version controlled or edited, it is designated for 3rd party software. You have two options. You can just grab the source from GitHub and put it somewhere where your Django app can find it (maybe fiddle with your python path) and add this location to git. Maybe even make your own fork on github. The second option is to use pip install -e github.com/project to have pip install an "editable" version. The advantage of the first way is better control over your changes, the advantage of the second way is having pip manage source download and install.

That being said, you seem kinda new to python environment. Are you *REALLY* sure you want to make your own fork? Is there some functionality you are missing that you want to add to the messages library? You do know that you can override every single template without changing the actual library code?

Comment: yes I am learning as I go here, I am really good at some parts, but lacking in others, I have been searching the docs looking for a good explanation on overriding templates and making simple changes to views if I need to, but I can't find it. Could you kindly point me in the right direction?

Comment: yes, that is it, and I have read that in its entirety, but I still have not seen an explanation on how to actually go about overriding a specific template or view

Comment: If that is the library, they have an actual customization page in docs
http://django-messages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#ref-messages-customization

Comment: figuring out how templates are being searched for and picked might be helpful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#template-loaders

Comment: in short, if you are not doing anything fancy, you should be able to put your custom templates into templates/django-messages directory at the root of your django app

Comment: Thanks foer the details. would modifying views be considered 'fancy?' Could I do this in somewhat  the same way as the template? It doesn't say in the link you posted.

Comment: No, by "fancy" I meant something like custom template loaders. Don't worry about it.

It looks like this library doesn't really want you to override the views, they want you to override forms. What functionality are you trying to add/change by overriding views?

Comment: Again, basic version. Chances are, you can do what you want without overriding any views. But if that is not the case, what you probably want to do is skip the part where you add django-messages to urls.py and use your own views instead.. Import everything you want from django-messages views and call them manually from inside your own views.

Comment: it was more of a theoretical question to help me in the future, but one aspect I definitely do need to edit would be the locale (translation) info the is in the venv installed directory. Can that be added in my project dir as well? I don't see any docs on doing that

Comment: I have never worked with localization in django. It looks like django-messages is properly localized though, so if your native language is missing, you should be able to add it without directly overwriting anything. Look at the django localization docs for more inspiration
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#how-to-create-language-files

Comment: thanks for answering my questions all the way through, you have been a big help

Comment: Also, if you make your own localization, you might want to send it to the project repo, so it gets included in the official sources

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100550/discussion-between-deltaskelta-and-mad-wombat).

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly how it is supposed to work. You track what libraries you install via your requirements.txt, which is committed along with your code. You use that file to generate your venv, and the libraries are installed there. You don't include the venv itself in your repo.

**Edit** The reason you are finding this hard is that **you are not supposed to do that**. Don't change third-party projects; you should never need to. They will be configurable.

If you really really find something you need to fix, do as suggested in the comments and fork the app. But this is definitely not something you need to do all the time, which points to the likelihood that you have not understood how to configure the apps from within your own project.

For example, in the case of customising templates, you can simply define the templates inside your own templates dir, rather than editing the ones provided with the app; Django does the right thing and uses yours first.

Comment: The corollary to this is that if you're making changes to python packages for your project, commit them to that project if you think they're useful. Or, since most are on github, keep them as your own fork and look up [git _sub-modules_](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

Comment: No need for sub-modules; fork them by all means, but then simply use the URL of the forked repo in the requirements.txt

Comment: so just add a bare directory with the same name in my project directory and add a templates (or whatever folder/file it may be) and django will use mine. I have never seen anything like this in the docs so I am a bit confused. Thank you for the answer so far